# AVErrorFailedToParse error thrown

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Can anyone provide anymore information on why I might get AVErrorFailedToParse when using MPMoviePlayerViewController.

AVError.h lists the error, but doesn't provide any other info.

```
AVErrorFailedToParse    NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0)        = -11853,
```

The error happens intermittently. So I'll try and play a mp4 and it will fail with this error, i'll try again immediately afterwards and it works.